# not able to see all file type images at a time when button clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I am using the below code to upload the image files from the system hard disk....

```
    private void btnAddimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        openFileDialog1.FileName = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png|jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|jpeg files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|gif files (*.gif)|*.gif";
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image image1 = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            pbProductImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pbProductImage.Image = image1;

        }

    }
```

its working fine but when i click on the btnaddimage the folder will be open with images those have extensions as file type (like png and jpeg and gif and jpeg)..

my problem is ....i am able not able to see the all file type images at a time..

at the first time a folder will be open with png files and then i have select another file type like jpeg from the combobox provided at the bottom right ....

is there any changes i need to do when i click the imagebutton to see the all file type images (rather than selecting the png files or jpeg files or gif files..like that ) at a time...

would any one pls give any idea for this..

many thanks....

Comment: Are you asking how to get the All Files (*.*) option in the OpenFileDialog box?  If so, just add `All files (*.*)|*.*` to your filter list.

Comment: ya all files but all files must be a image files(like jpeg and gif and jpg and png type files )...

Comment: @Tim if we specify allfiles we can see all text files and doc files and image files .. but i want only image files only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like (based on your comment) you want to have an option to see all the various file types at once (i.e., png, jpg, jpeg and gif).  If that's the case, try this in your filter:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png|jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|jpeg files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|gif files (*.gif)|*.gif|Image Files(*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif";
```

The last one combines several in one option - simply separate them by a semi-colon:

[FileDialog.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for filter value like this `images|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif` which will show all these types

Answer (score 0):

You can add All files (*.*)|*.* filter;

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png|jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|jpeg files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|gif files (*.gif)|*.gif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

Comment: it will shows all image files and other files also but i want only all types of image files .. Many thanks.....